# C# API Call: Null Exception at foreach loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to map API JSON data into some properties of a class, and I'm getting the error below. I was able to narrow down the data entry causing this issue.
[The value for PositionDateStart]

The script successfully creates an object off the properties, but once I call the object to test it using a `foreach` loop, it crashes and gives me this error.

My question is what could I write to tell the script to replace null with today's date if this comes up.

Thanks in advance!

---

Error Message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

---

JSON Results @Console.WriteLine(json)

```
[
    {
        "EntryID": 41992,
        "Position": "Associate",
        "PositionDateEnd": "2020-05-15T00:00:00",
        "PositionDateStart": null
    }
]
```

---

Script

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(json); //JSON results above
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Properties>>(json);

//Point at which code errors outs 
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.PositionDateStart);
    Console.WriteLine(item.PositionDateStart.GetType());
}
```

---

Class Properties

```
public class Properties
{
    public int EntryID { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PositionDateEnd { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PositionDateStart { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign current date if `PositionDateStart` is null then output to console anyway without errors since it will never be empty:

```
//Point at which code errors outs 
foreach (var item in result)
{
   if (item.PositionDateStart == null)
       item.PositionDateStart = DateTime.Now;
   Console.WriteLine(item.PositionDateStart);
   Console.WriteLine(item.PositionDateStart.GetType());
}
```

**EDIT**

As asked in comment, if you prefere to modify the class itself here is a variant through the get accessor so your `foreach` remains the same:

```
public class Properties
{
    public int EntryID { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PositionDateEnd { get; set; }

    private DateTime? _positionDateStart;
    public DateTime? PositionDateStart
    {
       get { return _positionDateStart == null ? DateTime.Now : _positionDateStart; }
       set { _positionDateStart = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. Do you know if it'd be possible to set this condition to the property in the Class Properties?

Comment: @ChunkyFresh You should be able to do that. See my edits. And also pls approve the answer, that's already two ;). Happy coding!

Comment: You got it. I tried this at the class level,and it worked perfectly. One last thing thoug.  I'm fairly new to C# sharp so I was wondering if you could point me to what I could read to understand the syntax you provided? Having a tough time deciphering what's going on inside the get/set part of it.

Comment: The `?:` syntax is called the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). You can see it as an if/else in one single line.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try (not tested):

```cs
Console.WriteLine(item?.PositionDateStart ?? DateTime.Now);
```

The null condional and null coalese operators are explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    if(item.PositionStartDate == null)
    {
        item.PositionDateStart = DateTime.Now;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(item.PositionDateStart.GetType());
}
```